# Scala - Null Handling RDD row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to access values in RDD row using getInt, getString. There are chances that this field can have nulls as well, due to which I end up in facing Null Pointer Exception. Can you please let me know what is the best way to fetch these values. Below is the syntax being used

`val field_no = row.getInt(3)`

`val field_name = row.getString(4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage some type safe options that Scala supports:

1. Try using pattern matching with the `Option` type (a container type in Scala that represents optional values and can be used to handle `null` values) returned by the `getAs` method:

```scala
val field_no = row.getAs[Int](3) match {
  case Some(value) => value
  case None => 0 // default value
}

val field_name = row.getAs[String](4) match {
  case Some(value) => value
  case None => null // default value
}
```

2. Try using `getOrElse` method as well:

```scala
val field_no = row.getAs[Int](3).getOrElse(0) // defaulting the null INT values to 0
val field_name = row.getAs[String](4).getOrElse(null) // defaulting the null STRING values to null
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the getOrElse method, is there a way to default null INT values to null itself instead of 0. I need the null to be present as is in my final RDD

Comment: @SriBharath Yes, you can then try using the `Integer` wrapper class in java, so it would go like `val field_no = Option(row.getAs[java.lang.Integer](3)).getOrElse(null)`. This will replace the null values with actual `null`.

Comment: Yes, that is fine. But I don't want to change the return type. I would like to have it as ```Int``` itself rather than ```Option[Int}```. Does this return the type as Int?

Comment: It will return `field_no: java.lang.Integer` not `Option[Int]`

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, just check for null first

```scala
val field_no = if (row.isNullAt(3)) defaultValue else row.getInt(3)

val field_name = if (row.isNullAt(4)) defaultValue else row.getString(4)
```

Or just use scala.util.Try to convert nullable to Option

```scala
import scala.util.Try

val field_no: Option[Int] = Try { row.getInt(3) }.toOption // None if null
val field_name: Option[String] = Try { row.getString(4) }.toOption // None if null
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I have null as a default value? Basically, if the field has value i need to retrieve it else it should populate as null. When I try to give null as default value it says ```error: an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion``` . Any idea how to handle this without going for an Option way